# Why does matplotlib not work on my Mac Os X recently updated to El Capitan?

Tags: python, matplotlib, osx-elcapitan

I recently upgraded to Mac OsX El Capitan and found some issues running a python script that was working perfectly fine before I upgraded. Running my script, which basically produces several plots using matplotlib, yields this error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1811, in inner
return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3873, in scatter
marker_obj = mmarkers.MarkerStyle(marker)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 171, in __init__
self.set_marker(marker)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 255, in set_marker
self._recache()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 193, in _recache
self._marker_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 331, in _set_mathtext_path
usetex=rcParams['text.usetex'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 445, in __init__
usetex=usetex)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 525, in text_get_vertices_codes
verts, codes = text_to_path.get_text_path(prop, s, usetex=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 150, in get_text_path
glyph_info, glyph_map, rects = self.get_glyphs_tex(prop, s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 304, in get_glyphs_tex
dviread.find_tex_file('pdftex.map'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 864, in find_tex_file
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
 raise child_exception
 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm using Python 2.7.11 and matplotlib 1.5.0

Comment: Looks like it cannot find `pdftex.map`?  ... should be in the directory specified by the `TEXFONTMAPS` environment var.

Comment: It looks like El Capitan has made some changes for security - your existing latex install probably used `/usr/texbin` which is no longer allowed, it should now be in `/Library/TeX/texbin`?

Comment: Thanks Hugh Bothwell, your comments were illuminating, I reinstalled MacTex, and restarted, after that matplotlib works fine.